# Using loop to repeat same steps but with other criteria

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, range, worksheet

I struggle with the coding below where I want to repeat all the steps but with different criteria declared before based on a cell value in my active workbook. 
I pointed out where it is blocking...

Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Validation()
Dim wbk As Workbook, wkshm As Worksheet, wksGI As Worksheet, wks1 As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet, wks3 As Worksheet
Dim wbkNew As Workbook, WSnew1 As Worksheet, WSnew2 As Worksheet, WSnew3 As Worksheet, wsnewGI As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim RNG1 As String, RNG2 As String, RNG3 As String, RNG As String, WSnew(3) As Worksheet, wks(3) As Worksheet
Dim sheettype As String, worksht1 As String, worksht2 As String, worksht3 As String, i, sh As Integer, worksht As String

Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksGI = wbk.Sheets("General Info & Validation")
Set wkshm = wbk.Sheets("Homepage")
Set wbkNew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
Set wsnewGI = wbkNew.Worksheets(1)
sheettype = wkshm.range("TYPE")
RNG = "RNG"
worksht = "worksht"
wsnewGI.Name = wksGI.Name

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Select Case sheettype
    Case "FAC-19"
        worksht3 = "FAC-19"
        worksht2 = "FAC-19 rebate analysis"
        worksht1 = "FAC-19 Comments"
        RNG3 = "A1:K258"
        RNG2 = "A1:AF73"
        RNG1 = "A1:J90"
        sh = 3
    Case "FAC-20"
        worksht2 = "FAC-20"
        worksht1 = "FAC-19 rebate analysis"
        RNG2 = "A1:N140"
        RNG1 = "A1:AF73"
        sh = 2
    Case "Bid Summary"
        worksht3 = wbk.Sheets("Advance Validation Bid").Name
        worksht2 = wbk.Sheets("Bid Summary").Name
        worksht1 = wbk.Sheets("Bid Rebate Analysis").Name
        RNG1 = "A1:AG78"
        RNG2 = "A1:AF187"
        RNG3 = "A1:M99"
        sh = 3
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Nothing to request for validation!", vbInformation, " No validation"
        Exit Sub
End Select

For i = 1 To sh
    Set WSnew(i) = wbkNew.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(wsnewGI.Name))
    Set wks(i) = wbk.Sheets(worksht & i)  >As from here it blocks
    WSnew(i).Name = wks(i).Name  
    Set RNG(i) = wks(i).range(RNG & i) 
    RNG(i).Copy
    With WSnew(i)
        With .range("A1")
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
        .Activate
        .range("A1").Select
        With .PageSetup
            .PrintArea = RNG & i
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesTall = 1
            .FitToPagesWide = 2
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.6)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.6)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        End With
    End With
Next i

For Each ws In wbkNew.Worksheets
    ws.Select
    With ActiveWindow
        .Zoom = 85
        .DisplayGridlines = False
    End With
Next ws

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Fairly sure you can't build variable names in that way in VBA (though I stand to be corrected). You would be better off storing worksht1 etc in an array and referencing the relevant element.

Comment: SJR, thx for your quick reply but as I'm not well known with arrays and how to build these in, I struggle.. Therefore some help would be nice. Thx.

Comment: You are already using them though, e.g. WSnew? Note that by default arrays start at zero, not one. If you are still stuck, I will post back with some amended code later if nobody else has intervened in the meantime.

Comment: I'd bet that, although `WSnew` is defined as an array, that was not the intention. But I may be wrong.

Comment: SRJ, thanks. Indeed I already worked with the array  but like mentioned by CMArg, it was not really the intention.. I played around a little bit further after your comment and i found the solution. See below the answer which did it.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Validation()
Dim wbk As Workbook, wkshm As Worksheet, wksGI As Worksheet
Dim wbkNew As Workbook, wsnewGI As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim RNG(3) As String, WSnew(3) As Worksheet, wks(3) As Worksheet
Dim sheettype As String, i As Integer, sh As Integer, worksht(3) As String, rnges(3) As range

Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksGI = wbk.Sheets("General Info & Validation")
Set wkshm = wbk.Sheets("Homepage")
Set wbkNew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
Set wsnewGI = wbkNew.Worksheets(1)
sheettype = wkshm.range("TYPE")
wsnewGI.Name = wksGI.Name

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Select Case sheettype
    Case "FAC-19"
        worksht(3) = "FAC-19"
        worksht(2) = "FAC-19 rebate analysis"
        worksht(1) = "FAC-19 Comments"
        RNG(3) = "A1:K258"
        RNG(2) = "A1:AF73"
        RNG(1) = "A1:J90"
        sh = 3
    Case "FAC-20"
        worksht(2) = "FAC-20"
        worksht(1) = "FAC-19 rebate analysis"
        RNG(2) = "A1:N140"
        RNG(1) = "A1:AF73"
        sh = 2
    Case "Bid Summary"
        worksht(3) = "Advance Validation Bid"
        worksht(2) = "Bid Summary"
        worksht(1) = "Bid Rebate Analysis"
        RNG(3) = "A1:AG78"
        RNG(2) = "A1:AF187"
        RNG(1) = "A1:M99"
        sh = 3
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Nothing to request for validation!", vbInformation, " No validation"
        Exit Sub
End Select

For i = 1 To sh
    Set WSnew(i) = wbkNew.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(wsnewGI.Name))
    Set wks(i) = wbk.Sheets(worksht(i)) 
    WSnew(i).Name = wks(i).Name
    Set rnges(i) = wks(i).range(RNG(i))
    rnges(i).Copy
    With WSnew(i)
        With .range("A1")
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
        .Activate
        .range("A1").Select
        With .PageSetup
            .PrintArea = RNG(i)
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesTall = 1
            .FitToPagesWide = 2
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.6)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.6)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        End With
    End With
Next i

For Each ws In wbkNew.Worksheets
    ws.Select
    With ActiveWindow
        .Zoom = 85
        .DisplayGridlines = False
    End With
Next ws

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you want, but it may help you to get started. Create a new excel, name the sheets as "MySheet1", "MySheet2" and "MySheet3", and run the following code. I would like to point out that, inside the loop, Worksheets are not treated as array elements. I may be wrong, but think you should think that piece of your code again.

```
Private Sub Example()
    Dim a(3) As Variant 'An array

    Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook

    a(1) = "MySheet1"
    a(2) = "MySheet2"
    a(3) = "MySheet3"

    For i = 1 To 3
        Set wks = wbk.Sheets(a(i)) 'This line is key to what you want to achieve
        wks.Cells(1, 1) = "Hi, you're in sheet number " & i & " and is named " & a(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You declared the sheet as variant, but is this needed?

Comment: I'm not declaring the sheets as variant. I'm declaring an array (`a`) as variant. Array elements contains the name of the sheets.